# middleware that will run before all other handlers

Tags: go, gorilla

I have this in main:

```
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        glog.Info("before")
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/people", person.GetMany).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/people/{id}", person.GetOne).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/people/{id}", person.Create).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/people/{id}", person.Delete).Methods("DELETE")
```

this mean that nothing got hit except the first middleware handler, so I tried creating a new router to handle the logging:

```
    mux.NewRouter().PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        glog.Info("before")
    })
```

but this new router doesn't get hit AND none of my other routes get hit. What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware is registered by calling [Router.Use](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Use)

Sample code is [here](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#middleware)

Your code should be:

```
router.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        glog.Info("before")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
})
```